Can an amplifier's slew rate vary based on input voltage? (Cathode Ray Tube display)
I have for several years now been interested in CRT (Cathode Ray Tube) displays and the science behind them. I do not have a large amount of electrical engineering experience, but I've learned enough to know the bare bones basics behind amplifier slew rates and how that affects the way a CRT display renders an image (the video amps' slew rate causes horizontal blur by taking time to transition colors from left to right).
I won't go too much into the specifics of the CRT display, since really this is a more general question about slew rates and how they work. My understanding is that slew rate, on a graph of time vs voltage, is a limitation on slope: the slew rate determines the maximum amount the voltage can change per unit time: 
However, what I've experienced from studying CRT displays - at least visually, from what I can see of the way colors transition - is something different. Essentially what I commonly see is that, depending on how large the difference in input is, the steeper the slope on the output, such that the slew time is roughly the same regardless of how large the input differential is. I've drawn a graph of what this would look like here: 
Here, the slew time is the same for both cases, and the slew rate seems to increase as a function of the change in voltage.
My question is whether this is actually something that would be possible, where the slew rate of an amplifier is variable like this depending on the input differential. There are a lot of things going on with CRT displays and it's possible that I'm mistaken in some way about what I'm seeing, but it'd be an awful huge coincidence for it to just happen to look like this so many times so consistently. So I'm wondering if anyone has any insight here that could be helpful to my understanding.

More generally, this applies to any amplifier, not just those employed for CRT drive.
A wideband amplifier might have a single or double pole response, i.e. flat frequency response up to cutoff, then dropping at 20 or 40 dB/dec beyond there.
This gives a corresponding single or double exponential transient response, where the slew rate dV/dt is simply proportional to amplitude.
The response is just an example; it can be any transient response in general, and dV/dt is proportional to amplitude; we defined it as a linear amplifier, this is a given.
Slew rate is an important figure for other reasons.  Namely, when an amplifier is nonlinear.
In a typical implementation, we have a diff pair and current mirror driving a  common-emitter amplifier (in turn loaded by CCS):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

For small signals, the response is straightforward; notice the input error is small.  For errors of 10s of mV (a magnitude proportional to thermal voltage \$\frac{k_B T}{e}\$), the diff pair remains ~linear and operation is normal.  For larger signals,

the diff pair saturates all the way to one side, putting I1 into Q5-B (and C1).  Since the base voltage doesn't move much, nor the current (until error gets down to a few 10s mV), so the slope is pretty straight and thus we have slew-rate limiting.  Note that the rising and falling slopes aren't equal, a common gotcha in amplifier design of this type.
In a more conventional class A wideband/RF amp design, linearity and dynamic range (power before significant distortion) are good, and slew rate limiting doesn't happen, at least until such limits are hit.  From this perspective, the diff pair is going class B, current doesn't go higher than I1 and effective bandwidth falls as a result (risetime increases).
A typical CRT load is capacitive (whether grid or cathode (video) drive, or deflection plates), so having ample current available to drive at the maximum required signal level avoids slew rate limitations and maintains bandwidth.  Peaking strategies are also quite beneficial, for example the output collector/drain capacitance can be resonated against the CRT capacitance with a tapped (tee coil) inductor to particular benefit (about double bandwidth).  (Whereas for a capacitive (collector/drain) source into a resistive load, series peaking can only gain about 30%.)

I provide a plot from Pressman's book here that illustrates the linearity of the diff pair when small difference signals are provided. But it also illustrates how that changes with larger signals. Just to add to what you wrote.

Big thanks for the quick response, although unfortunately I'm like 8 million years behind understanding like 90% of what you wrote. :( So I don't know how to interpret an answer to my question out of this.

Well, this is an engineering stack; without further direction, I'll assume familiarity with engineering as a baseline. Could you say more about what you are familiar with?
